# making file executable works only from GUI, not Terminal

Tags: command-line, permissions

From GUI this works:
open file properties menu -> Permissions Tab -> check "Allow executing file as a program"

From terminal running `chmod -x filename` doesn't do anything, nor outputs anything.

Things I've tried:

```
# 1
$ chown $USER filename
$ sudo chmod -x filename

# 2 
$ sudo chmod -x filename

# 3
$ chmod -777 filename
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your command `chmod -x`
deprives the execution permission. if you want to make it executable try:

```
chmod +x filename
```

Comment: holy shit can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 1):

To check your permissions you can `cd` to the desired folder and then do a `ls -l` , which will then display the permissions along with the filenames just like this:

[image: check the right side]

Here you can see there are a bunch of `.cpp` files which contain some C++ code , look at their permissions `-rw-r--r--` which means they are can be read by everyone but can only be written by the owner. Thus

- **r** : readable
- **w** : writable
- **x** : executable

And

- Last three Places : Others Permissions
- Next three Places : Group Permissions
- And the last Four places : Owner Permissions (the `d` means its a directory)

Now you can add and remove permissions with `chmod` , where ,

- **u** : Owner
- **g** : Group
- **o** : Other
- **a** : All

For example , as in your case to add the executable permission for the owner you can use the command `chmod u+x <filemane>` .

**Note** : Using a `-` instead of a `+` in the above command will remove that permission , for example to prevent others from reading you can use this command : `chmod o-r <filename>`